# vista ultimate boot from vhd

Tags: windows-vista, boot, vhd

> [Windows 7: Boot from VHD First
>   Impression: Part 3 (Booting VHD from
>   Vista SP1 or later)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/aviraj/archive/2009/01/28/windows-7-boot-from-vhd-first-impression-part-3-booting-vhd-from-vista-sp1-or-later.aspx)
>
> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to boot Vista from vhd using Windows 7 boot manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/66379/is-it-possible-to-boot-vista-from-vhd-using-windows-7-boot-manager)

Hi All,

Can you boot from vhd using Vista Ultimate?

Comment: As far as I know, this is only supported on Windows 7.

Comment: [No](http://superuser.com/questions/66379/is-it-possible-to-boot-vista-from-vhd-using-windows-7-boot-manager)